# Bootstrap modal contents for datatables actions column showing in console

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4

I want a modal to popup when i click on the options in my Actions dropdown

I have successfully displayed the rows from my db using jquery ajax. The Actions column contains a dropdown with different options in which if i click any one, it pops a modal concerning it.
Looking at the code below, `$actions` is what i return to the datatable as my column for the actions.

`$actions = <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Action
            </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
             <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#con'.$row['issue_id'].'" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Confirmed</a>
            </div>';
            // function with the modal in it
            status2($row['issue_id'], $row['resolved_by'], $conn, $row['resolution_date']);`

I want a modal to open when i click on confirmed, but the contents of the modal displays in my console instead, and no rows are returned to my datatable. Is that the correct way to place the modal?

Answer (score -1):

You can use ajax to perform certain action or open model popup by using onclick function

You can refer this link for ajax
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp